# MySQL very slow query count with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query and it has almost 500k data.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS Toplam
    FROM  userpersonel p
    INNER JOIN  usermessagecontent m  ON p.ID = m.MeID
    WHERE  p.VIP = 0
      AND  p.BotStatus = 0
      AND  m.End = 0
```

I'm trying it on the local database and it queries in about 2 minutes.

How can I decrease the time?

Comment: Make sure your `m.MeID` has an index associated with it. You can also run the query with `EXPLAIN SELECT..` to see what MySQL does, which indexes it uses, ..  A simple join with a basic select like this, on a relatively small dataset, should be almost instant.

Comment: for optimization questions, we need to know more details about your schema and how mysql is choosing to run your query; please edit your question to add (as text) output of `show create table userpersonel;` and `show create table usermessagecontent;` and `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) AS Toplam FROM userpersonel p INNER JOIN usermessagecontent m ON p.ID = m.MeID WHERE p.VIP = 0 AND p.BotStatus = 0 AND m.End = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Toplam
FROM userpersonel p INNER JOIN
     usermessagecontent m 
     ON p.ID = m.MeID
WHERE p.VIP = 0 AND p.BotStatus = 0 AND m.End = 0;
```

you have two indexing strategies, depending on which of the `WHERE` clause filters are more restrictive.

One is:

- `userpersonel(VIP, BotStatus, Id)`
- `usermessagecontent(Meid, end)`

The second is:

- `userpersonel(id, VIP, BotStatus)`
- `usermessagecontent(end, Meid)`

Comment: Can you give me an example query about it?

Comment: @ardalegent the query is just your query; Gordon is telling you what indexes you would have to be optimal for this query

Comment: @ysth I don't know what you mean by that. I am asking for an example of how can I.

Comment: @ardalegent . . . `create index . . . `.